# Import fbx not working in blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, export, camera, import

I exported a model from rhino as a .fbx file and tried opening it up on blender but its not popping up. I tried changing the units to see if that was the problem but it still does not work. I also tried exporting and importing as a .obj but it is still blank in blender. In blender it shows on 'layers; persay that there is objects there they just cant be seen for some reason. I attached a screenshot for reference! [image]

Comment: You aught to edit your topic to include "rhino" in the subject

Comment: 1) are you sure it’s blank and not just huge or way off-origin? Use “Frame Selected” to try and find it. 2) are you sure you didn’t make a Rhino export error? try re-exporting or exporting a different model.